# Debug the nestjs project in vscode using docker does not work

Tags: node.js, docker, debugging, docker-compose, nestjs

I have a NestJs project using docker and I would like to debug it in VSCode.

In package.json, I have:
`"start:debug": "nest start --debug 0.0.0.0:9229 --watch"`

In docker-compose, I have:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  core-database:
    image: postgis/postgis:latest
    volumes:
      - /tmp/rg-core/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=***
      - POSTGRES_USER=***
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
  core-service:
    container_name: core-service
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev

    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

    ports:
      - 9001:9001
      #debugging port
      - 9229:9229

      # Database
      - DB_HOST=***
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_NAME=***
      - DB_USER=***
      - DB_PASSWORD=***
    
    command: 'yarn run start:debug'
```

In launch.json, I have:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229,
            "request": "attach",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "node",
            "address": "0.0.0.0",
            "restart": true,
            "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm running docker compose up and giving start debugging in VSCode, but it's not stopping at the breakpoint.

Am I doing something wrong? how should it be done?

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to deal with the same problem for a few days now.

From my research, VS Code Debug Console by default is listening for `console.log`s. However *NestJS Logger* is logging to `stdout/stderr` (`process.stdout.write`), so `launch.json` needs the additional line:

```
{
  ... ,
  "outputCapture": "std"
}
```

Sadly, it is still not enough to make it work.

To workaround this for now, I'm attaching a running container's terminal to VS Code integrated terminal manually, executing `docker container attach --no-stdin <container-name>`.

This is still not a real solution so I hope someone brings one. Thank you for raising this issue. Can you share the contents of your *Dockerfile* for full reference?

Answer (score -1):

Was missing port 9229 export in Dockerfile.

In the package.json: `"dev": "nest start --debug 0.0.0.0:9229 --watch"`

In the docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  core-database:
    image: postgis/postgis:latest
    volumes:
      - /tmp/rg-core/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=***
      - POSTGRES_USER=***
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
  core-service:
    container_name: core-service
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev

    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

    ports:
      - 9001:9001
      #debugging port
      - 9229:9229

      # Database
      - DB_HOST=***
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_NAME=***
      - DB_USER=***
      - DB_PASSWORD=***
    
    command: 'yarn run dev'
```

In the launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug core-service",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true
    }
  ]
}
```

In the Dockerfile:

```
...

EXPOSE 9001 9229
```

Comment: Exposing the port in the Dockerfile functionally changes nothing. As per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)
> "The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published."

There are various changes between your original post and this one so it's hard to say what fixed the problem, but my guess would be that you simply rebuilt the image (and hadn't in a while)